# asp.net Active directory membership Provider

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, membership-provider

I need to use the AD Membership provider for authentication and Authorization for a project. I however do not have access to a domain controller. Is there any way I can simulate either a domain controller or AD implementation on a Windows 2003 Server, given that I cannot make the server a Domain Controller?

Comment: Can't you utilize an existing DC on the network? No need to make your app server a DC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use ADAM - Active Directory Application Mode (ADAM).   See remarks - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.activedirectorymembershipprovider.aspx

ADAM can be downloaded here ... http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=9688f8b9-1034-4ef6-a3e5-2a2a57b5c8e4&displaylang=en